# Azure devops pipeline - Specific verion for Sqlpackage

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In my azure devops release pipeline, i need to specify to use the latest version of sqlpackage.

For my case, both options specifying "latest" or giving a specific verion of sqlpackage are fine.

How to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demands are not a request to install some software. That is just a filter to find needed software if it exists on a build agent properties. To install the latest version, you may try to use the following: [Installation, cross-platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver16#installation-cross-platform)

yaml example:

```
steps:
- script: |
   dotnet tool install -g microsoft.sqlpackage
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'

- script: 'sqlpackage -version'
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'
```

result:

[image]